Optimizing SQL UPDATE Query with Conditional Data Retrieval from Multiple Tables
I have three table:

dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_API
dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER
dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_3PTY

My target table is table 1 i.e dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_API.
The source tables are 2. dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER and 3. dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_3PTY.
The problem statment is as follows:

First, check for ALIAS_PN column in dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_API. If ALIAS_PN IS NULL, then data should come from dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER. In dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER, data should be coming from DESCRIPTION column to SHORT_DESCRIPTION column in dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_API.
If ALIAS_PN IS NOT NULL, the data should come from namely two columns from dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_3PTY. SHORT_DESC and DESC1 . But the condition as to which column that the data should be coming from is below.

The data should be primarily coming from SHORT_DESC. But If SHORT_DESC is NULL for dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_3PTY, then DESC1 column in dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_3PTY should be assigned to target column SHORT_DESCRIPTION in dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_API



I have come up with this below SQL query:
-----v1.0
UPDATE AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_API A
SET SHORT_DESCRIPTION = (
  CASE
    WHEN A.ALIAS_PN IS NULL THEN (SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER WHERE dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER.PN = A.PN)
    ELSE COALESCE((SELECT SHORT_DESC FROM AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_3PTY WHERE dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_3PTY.PN = A.PN), (SELECT DESC1 FROM AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_3PTY WHERE dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_3PTY.PN = A.PN))
  END
);

I have further optimized the query to:
----v1.1
UPDATE AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_API A
SET SHORT_DESCRIPTION = 
  COALESCE(
    (SELECT M.DESCRIPTION FROM AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER M WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER MT WHERE MT.PN = A.PN) AND A.ALIAS_PN IS NULL),
    (SELECT COALESCE(P.SHORT_DESC, P.DESC1) FROM AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_3PTY P WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_3PTY PT WHERE PT.PN = A.PN) AND A.ALIAS_PN IS NOT NULL)
  );

When I try to run this, the UPDATE query is taking too much time to run.

This might be because the source tables and target table both contains over half a million records each.
Also, does duplicate PNs arise in the above subqueries?
That might also be the reason as to why the update is taking too long. How can I optimize this query?
If at all is the query valid?


Please read [mre] and Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?

half a million records need time, but do you really need to run this query often, usully you run this once and then have trigger that update a few rows

In your SQL (formatted for better clarity):
UPDATE AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_API A
   SET SHORT_DESCRIPTION = 
           COALESCE(
                    (SELECT M.DESCRIPTION
                      FROM AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER M
                     WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                     FROM AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER MT
                                    WHERE MT.PN = A.PN)
                       AND A.ALIAS_PN IS NULL),
                  (SELECT COALESCE(P.SHORT_DESC, P.DESC1)
                    FROM AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_3PTY P
                   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                   FROM AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_3PTY PT
                                  WHERE PT.PN = A.PN)
                     AND A.ALIAS_PN IS NOT NULL)
                    );

You have no join on M. Your WHERE EXISTS uses a subquery that references only A and MT. That will match all rows in M.
The same with the second argument to COALESCE: it too reads P but without any join. The WHERE EXISTS that filters it makes no reference to P so is uncorrelated - it will match all rows.
This query should actually error out by returning multiple rows to the COALESCE, which expects only one scalar value for each operand. It can't handle multiple rows.
There is a number of ways you can rewrite this. I'd probably do a merge which is much more flexible and easier to control for updates involving complex logic. For half million rows you might also want to enable parallel dml, though you don't really have to:
alter session enable parallel dml;

MERGE /*+ parallel(tgt,4) */ INTO AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_API tgt
USING (SELECT /*+ parallel(4) */ 
              A.ROWID row_id,
              COALESCE(M.DESCRIPTION,P.SHORT_DESC, P.DESC1) SHORT_DESCRIPTION
         FROM AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_API A,
              AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER M,
              AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_3PTY P
        WHERE DECODE(A.ALIAS_PN,NULL,A.PN) = M.PN(+)
          AND DECODE(A.ALIAS_PN,NULL,NULL,A.PN) = P.PN(+)) src
ON (src.row_id = tgt.ROWID)          
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE tgt.SHORT_DESCRIPTION = src.SHORT_DESCRIPTION

Note that I used DECODE to control which join was enabled based on your ALIAS_PN logic. You could use CASE as well. If you don't like native Oracle syntax (my preference) you can rewrite this quite simply using ANSI syntax; the same concept applies:
LEFT JOIN AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER M ON M.PM = DECODE(A.ALIAS_PN,NULL,A.PN)
Or even:
LEFT JOIN AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER M ON M.PM = A.PN AND A.ALIAS_PN IS NULL
etc.
The use of MERGE also allows us to use a more efficient parallelized hash join + full table scan for joining 100% of A to M and P. No indexes needed. With the normal UPDATE method, you definitely would need indexes on PN and the operation would be far less efficient at large volumes even when properly indexed.

It sounds like you just need a joined update. The syntax is different in different databases. In SQL Server it would be like this:
UPDATE a
SET SHORT_DESCRIPTION = 
  CASE WHEN a.ALIAS_PN IS NULL
       THEN m.DESCRIPTION
       ELSE ISNULL(p.SHORT_DESC, p.DESC1)
  END
FROM AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_API a
LEFT JOIN AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER m ON m.PN = a.PN
LEFT JOIN AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_3PTY p ON p.PN = a.PN;

To make this efficient, you would need to have all tables indexed on PN. Clustered indexes would be good, otherwise for non-clustered indexes make sure they INCLUDE the other columns mentioned.
In Oracle, you can't use a joined UPDATE. You could use two MERGE statements instead.
MERGE AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_API a
USING AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER m ON m.PN = a.PN AND a.ALIAS_PN IS NULL
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  SET SHORT_DESCRIPTION = m.DESCRIPTION;

MERGE AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_API a
USING AYaramati.dup_IMCS_IMCS_MASTER_3PTY p ON p.PN = a.PN AND a.ALIAS_PN IS NOT NULL
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  SET SHORT_DESCRIPTION = COALESCE(p.SHORT_DESC, p.DESC1);


It appears that you're trying to use T-SQL syntax in an Oracle SQL context. Oracle SQL does not support the FROM clause directly in an UPDATE statement in the same way that T-SQL does.

I see no indication in the question that this is Oracle, and I did say "The syntax is different in different databases." If it's Oracle you should tag accordingly.
